# 403 Forbidden Access to CodeIgniter controller from ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im having trouble with sending an ajax request to codeigniter controller. It is throwing back a 404 Forbidden Access error. I have found some sort of similar question to this but im not sure if its particular to CodeIgniter framework, and also the solution give in that thread did not solve my problem. below is my ajax request. Im wondering this is probably because of the .htaccess of the root folder of CI Application folder, but i dont want to change its default configuration yet.

Is sending ajax request to CI controller the correct way of implementing this? if not, any suggestion please. Thanks!

```
var ajax_load = '{loading gif img html}';
var ajax_processor = 'http://localhost/patientcare-v1/application/controller/ajax_processor/save_physical_info';

$("#save").click(function(){
    $("#dialog-form").html(ajax_load);
    $.post(
        ajax_processor,
        $("#physical-info").serialize(),
        function(responseText){
            $("#dialog-form").html(responseText);
        },
        "json"
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<code>` and `application/controller` from your `ajax_processor` like,

```
var ajax_processor = 'http://localhost/patientcare-v1/index.php/ajax_porcessor/save_physical_info';
```

If you are hiding `index.php` from `url` by using `htaccess` or `routing` then try this url,

```
var ajax_processor = 'http://localhost/patientcare-v1/ajax_porcessor/save_physical_info';
```

Comment: <code> tag was just for the formatting in asking the question. already corrected it.

Answer (score 7):

CodeIgniter use *csrf_protection*, you can use it with Ajax and JQuery simply.
This (ultimate ?) solution work on multiple Ajax request (no 403 ;-) and preserve the security).

## Change the configuration

Open the file /application/config/config.php
and change the line $config['csrf_token_name'] by :

```
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'token';
```

You can use another name, but change it everywhere in future steps.

## Add CSRF in your Javascript

Add script in a view; for me is in footer.php to display the code in all views.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CFG = {
        url: '<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url');?>',
        token: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>'
    };
</script>
```

This script create an object named *CFG*. This object can be used in your Javascript code. CFG.url contain the url of your website and CFG.token ... the token.

## Automatically renew the CSRF

Add this code in your part *$(document).ready(function($){---})* as

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajaxSetup({data: {token: CFG.token}});
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e,x) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(x.responseText);
        $('input:hidden[name="token"]').val(result.token);
        $.ajaxSetup({data: {token: result.token}});
    });
});
```

This script initialize the CSRF token and update it everytime when a request Ajax is sended.

## Send the CSRF in PHP

I've created a new controller, named Ajax. In CodeIgniter, the link to use it is http://www.domain.ltd/**ajax/foo**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    public function foo() {
        $this->send(array('foo' => 'bar'));
    }

    private function send($array) {

        if (!is_array($array)) return false;

        $send = array('token' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()) + $array;

        if (!headers_sent()) {
            header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
            header('Expires: ' . date('r'));
            header('Content-type: application/json');
        }

        exit(json_encode($send, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));

    }

}
```

The *send* function add the CSRF automatically and transform an array in object.

## The final result

Now, you can use Ajax with JQuery very simply !

```
$.post(CFG.url + 'ajax/foo/', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}, 'json');
```

Result :

```
{"token":"8f65cf8e54ae8b71f4dc1f996ed4dc59","foo":"bar"}
```

When the request get data, the CSRF is automatically updated to the next Ajax request.

Et voilà !

Comment: I love your solution and I'd like to add that when using the same page using AJAX in multiple tabs than that will still cause issues. The only way for me to circumvent that was to disable regeneration for those controllers. CSRF regen seems useless anyway, been reading up on that. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem but now I have fixed this problem.

First of all, I have created csrf_token in header.php for every pages like below code

```
$csrf = array(
                'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
                'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
        );

<script type="text/javascript">
    var cct = "<?php echo $csrf ['hash']; ?>";
  </script>
```

After that, when we are sending particular value through ajax then we will have to sent csrf token like below code

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo APPPATHS.'staff_leave/leaveapproval/getAppliedLeaveDetails'; ?>",
    data:{id:id,status:status,'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': cct},
    method:"post",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(response)
    {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

I hope this code will help you because this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Select URIs can be whitelisted from csrf protection (for example API 
    // endpoints expecting externally POSTed content). 
    // You can add these URIs by editing the 
    // ‘csrf_exclude_uris’ config parameter:
    
    // config.php
    // Below setting will fix 403 forbidden issue permanently
    
    $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
        'admin/users/view/fetch_user', // use ajax URL here
    );

$('#zero-config').DataTable({
            
                "processing" : true,
                "serverSide" : true,             
                "order" : [],
                "searching" : true,
                "ordering": false,
                "ajax" : {
                    url:"<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin/users/view/fetch_user",
                    type:"POST",
                    data: {                        
                    },
                },
                
            });
```