# Ajax post not working codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.1

Ajax post not working and i am getting 403 (Forbidden) in console.

[POST http://localhost/test/post 403 (Forbidden)]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="post">
                <input type="text" id="data1" name="data1" value="">
                <input type="text" id="data2" name="data2" value="">
            </div>
    <button id="post">Submit</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#post').on('click', function () {

      var value1=$("#data1").val();
      var value2=$("#data2").val();

        $.ajax({
                url: window.location.href+'/post',
                type: "POST",
                data:"{'data1':'"+value1+"','data2':'"+value2+"'}"
            });
```

**CONTROLLERS**

```
public function post() 
    {

        $data1 = $this->common->nohtml($this->input->post("data1", true));
        $data2 = $this->common->nohtml($this->input->post("data2", true));


        $this->data_models->update($this->data->INFO, array(
          "data1" => $data1,
          "data2" => $data2,
            )
          );

  }
```

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use? if more than jQuery 1.9.0
Try to change `type: "POST"` to `method: "POST"` ?.

Comment: Not working. I am using jQuery 1.12.4 @MateuszPalichleb

Comment: Do you have enabled `mod_rewrite` module in your environment? Maybe this is some problem with .htaccess

Comment: Yes............

Comment: You're POSTING data , so why are you using the `get()` method for the `input` class?

Comment: If you have enabled CSRF protection - anything that uses ajax to access a CodeIgniter URL must include the value of the hidden CSRF token. If you don't want this feature try add `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;` to your `config.php` file

Comment: No i want that but how to pass this if `csrf_protection` true? @MateuszPalichleb

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527412/403-forbidden-access-to-codeigniter-controller-from-ajax-request this should be help you using CSRF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want CSRF protection on (a good idea) then you must pass the CSRF token when posting form data - via AJAX or not. Consider this approach.

The easiest way to put the token in your form is to use Codeigniter's "Form Helper" ([Documented here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)) You can load the function your controller or use autoloading. This view code assumes you have the helper loaded.

**HTML**

```
<div class="post">
    <?= form_open('controller_name/post'); //makes form opening HTML tag ?> 
    <input type="text" id="data1" name="data1" value="">
    <input type="text" id="data2" name="data2" value="">
    <?php
    echo form_submit('submit','Submit', ['id'=>'post']); //makes standard "submit" button html
    echo form_close(); // outputs </form>
    ?>
</div>
```

The `form_open()` function also automatically adds a hidden field containing the CSRF token to the HTML.

**Javascript**

```
$('#post').submit(function( event ) {
    //the next line will capture your form's fields to a format 
    //perfect for posting to the server
  var postingData = $( this ).serializeArray();
  event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
    url: window.location.href + '/post',
        type: "POST",
        data: postingData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**controller**

By the time $_POST gets to your controller the CSRF token has been striped away so you don't have to worry about it "polluting" your incoming data.

```
public function post()
{
    //get all the posted data in one gulp and NO, you do not want to use xss_clean
    $posted = $this->input->post();
    //With the above the var $posted has this value (showing made up values)
    // array("data1" => "whatever was in the field", "data2" => "whatever was in the field");

    //sanitize the field data (?)
    //just stick the clean data back where it came from
    $posted['data1'] = $this->common->nohtml($posted["data1"]);
    $posted['data2'] = $this->common->nohtml($posted["data2"]);

    $this->data_models->update($this->data->INFO, $posted);

    //you must respond to the ajax in some fashion
    //this could be one way to indicate success 
    $response['status'] = 'success';
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

You could also send back some other status if, for instance, the model function reported a problem. You then need to react to that status in you javascript. But if you don't respond it will likely result in problems down the road.

Comment: Thank you. Can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238671/ajax-upload-not-working-codeigniter ?